# Install packages via pip

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

Encountered the next error while trying to `pip install matplotlib`
Don't know what to do, it managed to install small packages as `tqdm` or `requests`, but failed at something like `pandas, torch, numpy`, etc.[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zv7C.png)

Comment: ```distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\\users\\arsfi\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\arsfi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpwx2l0qmb', '--quiet', 'cppy>=1.1.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------```
The last line of the error message

Comment: The recommended way to cal pip is `python3.8 -m pip install PACKAGE_NAME`, specifying the intended python version, of course. You may be trying to install Matplotlib into an unintended environment. Also, I can see that you are suing Python 3.9, which has just been released. The may still be some compatibility issues. If that's the case, it may be worth to report them in the right place.

Comment: In my system, it complains about missing compilers for C++ while trying to install `numpy`. I definitely would try to use Python3.8 for now and submit an issue on the numpy project page, as well as any other that is not working properly.